# Apktool cmd commands do nothing

Tags: java, apktool

So I need to edit an apk. I've seen some guides on how to do it using apktool.

I have installed jre 1.7, Android SDK, and apktool.

I have put apktool.jar, apktool.bat and aapt.exe in the same folder (C:/apktool), and added framework-res.apk and the app I wish to edit to the folder.

Yet, when i write the command "apktool if framework-res.apk" in an admin launched CMD, nothing happens. No error occurs aswell. Also the command "apktool d " doesn't work and doesn't show any errors aswell.

Java is recognized by my computer, by the way.

Why don't I get any response from "apktool if" and "apktool d" when I try to run them through CMD?

I'll be happy to provide with any information you need.

Thanks in advance, Sagi.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: My specific question is why does nothing happen when I try to run apktool commands through CMD. I'll edit it into the post, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that the problem relies in apktool.bat, but since you get no output, we can't be sure what's wrong.

Please launch apktool directly from the .jar, using this command (cmd.exe):

```
java -jar apktool.jar d app_name.apk
```

Remember to run this command from the right directory (in you case C:\apktool) and make sure that you have java in your $PATH.

Good luck and welcome to stackoverflow.